# What is opposite of the phrase "Sprinting to the finish line"?

Tags: phrase-request

I am looking for the metaphoric opposite of the phrase "Sprinting to the finish line.

my context is "achieving something at a very slow, lethargic and unremarkable way".

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest

> Crawling to the finish line.

It will be familiar to your audience as a play on "sprinting to the finish line" and it captures what you mean. Other options (with other more specific meanings) include

> dragging one's feet (*delaying intentionally*) 
> making a meal of it/sth. (*taking more time then necessary*) 
> taking one's [sweet] time. (*doing something slowly, especially in a flagrant and unnecessary way*) 
> stumbling over the finish line (*doing something poorly just to get it done*)

Specific words that might be relevant include

> Dawdle 
> Dilly Daly 
> Lackluster 
> Half-heartedly 
> **Lackadaisical**

With the last being my favorite and a good option for your context.